# Stripping timestamp from Json int

Tags: python, json, split, timestamp

In a third-party script, it's meant to spit out Json for me to decode but instead prepends a timestamp:

```
2015-03-28T16:32:41.875199+00:00 {"1": {"Power (kW)": "0.301", "Energy Imported (kWh)": "62.281"...}}
```

All of this is in one big integer. I've tried to split this based on the space/whitespace contained before the first curly bracket but can simply not do it. I'd really appreciate some pointers - I'm aware my questions here are very basic, and apparently I'm going to be blocked soon unless I improve, so please don't shoot me for asking another simple one!

Updated 31/3/2015 for @Alex.

I realise it may seem impossible but assure you that it returns a datatype of int. You may not believe it, but you'll have to, and [check the guy's code here](https://github.com/edrabbit/neurio). This is what I've used to call the script:

```
get_power=os.system("python /fetch_neurio.py --ip 172.16.0.8 --format json --type sensor")
thedata = get_power
print type(thedata)
```

If you find that too unbelievable then look at the code of fetch_neurio yourself. If you're struggling to help a cretin like me, then no worries. I just came here to ask for help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you mean by "one big `int`" in the text **and** subject since pretty clearly the data is a **string**, not an integer.  I'm going to answer on the assumption that your repeated use of `int` is just a weird repeated typo and you meant "string" instead.

Given

```
data = '2015-03-28T16:32:41.875199+00:00 {"1": {"Power (kW)": "0.301", "Energy Imported (kWh)": "62.281"}}'
```

(removing the `...` to make the JSON part syntactically valid),

```
import json

timestamp, jsondata = data.split(None, 1)
pythondata = json.loads(jsondata)
```

...yep, it **is** as simple as this!-)

"Splitting on `None`" means to split on sequences of 1+ whitespace characters (in case that blank-looking thing might be a tab or whatever, we don't care:-).  The second optional argument, here `1`, to the split method, means to do just one split (on the very first sequence of whitespace) -- thus producing two pieces that we assign correspondingly to two variables.

There are of course other possibilities, for example using regular expressions, if the anomalies in `data` are worse than you have communicated so far (i.e, more than just a pre-pended, whitespace separated timestamp), but based on what you **have** communicated, this simplistic approach should suffice.

Comment: Well, why is it when I request its type does it return <type 'int'> ?

Comment: @Will, it is, simply, absolutely impossible, for `type()` called on the string you show us, to respond with `<type 'int'>`.  If you see the latter, you must, instead, be calling `type` on something very different than the string you show us in your question.  Please edit your Q to show exactly what data you're calling `type` on (presumably by `print`ing both `repr(data)` and  `type(data)`) and if the bug in your code is not obvious to you I'll be glad to point it out (if you give us enough info to do so).

Comment: @Will, **of course** `os.system` returns an `int`, **no matter what** separate process you're running with it -- that return value is the exit **status** of said separate process and has **absolutely nothing** to do with the string you show at the start of the Q!  Rather, that line gets written to `output.log` (you could ask for a different filename with an `--outputfile` argument to that script, as easily determined by eyeballing said script).  So, forget the irrelevant status code returned from `os.system`, read the last line of `output.log`, and parse **that**!

Comment: OK, Alex. Thanks. I think I'll just forget it and find another way, and another site. I find your tone pretty impossible to deal with, but I'm grateful for your help anyway. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

pass `maxsplit` the second argument to split as 1.

```
'2015-03-28T16:32:41.875199+00:00 {"1": {"Power (kW)": "0.301", "Energy Imported (kWh)": "62.281"...}}'.split(' ',1)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see on the screen (a line that starts with `2015-03-28...`) is the *output* from the shell command that you've started using `os.system()` function. It is printed directly to stdout. `os.system()` returns the exit code from the command (an integer); it does not return the output.

To capture the output from a subprocess, you could use: [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Or (better) import the module and call the appropriate functions, to get the result without unnecessary external process and printing/parsing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fetch_neurio #NOTE: make sure fetch_nerio.py's directory is in pythonpath

url = 'http://{ip}/both_tables.html'.format(ip='172.16.0.8')
(timestamp, data) = fetch_neurio.fetch_page(url, localtime=False)
parsed_data = fetch_neurio.parse_readings(data)
readings = fetch_neurio.get_sensor_readings(parsed_data)
# use timestamp, readings here..
```